# B1/B2 visa lost along with my passport

Tags: visas, south-african-citizens, lost-documents

I have lost my passport with my B1/B2 visa in it still valid for 5 years. I am still in my home country, will they put the visa into my new passport free of charge or do I need to go through everything again?

Comment: They will put a new visa for free (or maybe with a lower fee) in the new passport, but you have to prove that the old one was lost/stolen.

Comment: @JuanCa I am skeptical of that claim.  Do you have a reference to support it?  If so, you should post an answer.

Comment: @phoog That happened to a friend (but in that case, the passport was stolen) in US embassy, in my home country (Ecuador). If that is not a valid reference, no problem, I can delete the comment.

Comment: @JuanCa not at all, personal experience is perfectly valid.  Post an answer.  I'll upvote it.

Comment: I don't know how to "prove" you lost your passport, though.

Comment: @JuanCa Take a look at BritishSam's Answer below, which describes what the passport/visa owner must do in order to satisfy the US Embassy or Consulate to issue a new visa.

Answer (score 6):

You need to report it to your US consulate or Embassy for a replacement visa. You will need a new appointment like when you got your visa, you will also have to pay again. Also you will have to provide a written account of how you lost your passport containing your visa.

> **Report your Visa Lost/Stolen to the U.S. Embassy or Consulate Abroad**
>
> To report your visa lost or stolen, email the Consular Section at the
>   U.S. Embassy or Consulate outside the United States which issued your
>   visa. Go to the [U.S. Embassy or Consulate website](http://www.usembassy.gov/) to locate the
>   email address and contact information. Be sure to include your full
>   name, date of birth, place of birth, address in the United States, and
>   an e-mail address (if available). Specifically state whether the visa
>   was lost or stolen. If you have a copy of the passport or visa, scan
>   and email this to the embassy or consulate. Otherwise, if known,
>   report the category of visa, and the passport number from the
>   lost/stolen visa.
>
> If you have already reported your visa lost/stolen to the U.S. Embassy
>   or Consulate, and then you later find your misplaced visa, then your
>   visa will be invalid for future travel to the United States. 
>   Therefore, in that situation you must apply for a new visa at the U.S.
>   Embassy or Consulate.
>
> **Applying for a Replacement U.S. Visa**
>
> Lost or stolen U.S. visas cannot be replaced in the United States. For
>   replacement of a visa, you must apply in person at a U.S. Embassy or
>   Consulate abroad. When applying for the replacement of a visa, you
>   will need to provide a written account documenting the loss of your
>   passport and visa. Include a copy of the police report.

[Travel.State.Gov](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/lost-stolen-visas.html)